# What does the colon mean in the list of ports when running kubectl get services

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

If I run `kubectl get services` for a simple demo service I get the following response:

```
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
demo-service   LoadBalancer   10.104.48.115   <pending>     80:32264/TCP   18m
```

What does the : mean in the port list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

External access to the demo-service will happen via port 32264, which connects to port 80 on the docker container.

Answer (score 5):

Meaning `80:32264/TCP` this is,

You have demo-service and it is pointing 80 port to your pod and 32264/TCP means you can use NodeIP for accessing the application which is running in pod from external network (outside of  cluster). And the `:` will separate these ports for your understanding which is external and internal port for accessing pod.

Answer (score 5):

This means that your service `demo-service` can be reached on port 80 from other containers and on the NodePort 32264 from the "outer" world.

In this particular case it will be accessed by Load Balancer which is provisioned/managed by some sort of Kubernetes controller.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is old, I want to write a different answer.

For Loadbalancer type of service, the port before : is the port your service exposed, usually specified by admin in service yaml file. The port after ':' is a random NodePort on the node, usually assigned by system.